# Как прочитать файл xlsx библиотекой PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, openpyxl

Здравствуйте,
помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос.

Есть файл **Excel** который создан с помощью библиотеки **Openpyxl** (файл получаю от поставщика).
Пытаюсь прочитать этот файл с помощью **PHPExcel**.
В результате получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message
>   'Your requested sheet index: -1 is out of bounds. The actual number of
>   sheets is 0.'

Что это означает понимаю.
Файл создан с нестандартными `namespace ( s:, x: )`.

Пытаюсь решить вопрос по данному совету (везде советуют одно и тоже):
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1187#issuecomment-295032648

Результат остается тот же.

Как можно решить данный вопрос, не подскажите?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: пример файла приложите

Comment: Тут файл excel: https://fex.net/#!794713060819

Comment: покажите код, который используете для открытия файла

Comment: Это если по совету:
`$inputFileName = 'grupa-d-82566(1).xlsx';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
include 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007_XNamespace.php';
$excelReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007_XNamespace();
$objPHPExcel = $excelReader->load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sheetData);
echo '</pre>';`

Comment: С этим же кодом файлы сохраненные в Excel, открываются без проблем.

Comment: Если вдруг кому будет интересно, вопрос закрыл другой библиотекой.
Отлично справилась с задачей плюс может читать большие файлы в которых строк более 200 тыс.
Посмотреть можно тут: 
http://opensource.box.com/spout/